# pdfpages does not write to toc using KOMA book class

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, pdfpages, scrbook

I am writing my thesis in a cumulative way, and therefore want to include the already published papers via the pdfpages package. It nicely includes them, and in case of the figures and tables, the entries are passed to the lists and can be accessed using hyperref.
However, for the sections and subsections, the "text" is not passed on, i.e. I get the number, as well as the indentation and the page number into the toc, however not the text.

I use normally XeLaTeX-->Biber-->XeLaTeX.

[image]

I tried to reduce the code as much as possible (but left all the class options and hyperref options):

```
% ===== File mainthesis.tex - Dissertation ======
\documentclass[
version=last,                   %always uses the latest version of KOMA Script (currently 3.28)
draft=false,                    % draft option on, i.e. small black boxes on the end of paragraphs needing post processing and others.
overfullrule=false,         % also lerading to black boxes, but no other effect compared to draft mode.
paper=a4,                       % size
oneside,                        % indicates two side printing, affects margins, as well as vertical stretching to achieve same level of bottom line.
open=any,                   % also enables chapters to start on the left page AND right page. Alternatively use "right" or "left".
fontsize=11pt,              % main font size, which affects further sizing using large, huge, tiny etc.
numbers=noenddot,           % title without dot
toc=bibliography,           % bibliography in the table of content
listof=totoc,
BCOR=12mm,              % binding correction, i.e. margin added to coorect for the amount of paper "lost" because of binding, ask the printer before how much this will be.
DIV=calc,                       
headings=big,               %normal sized headings(chapter/section titles), default is "big"
headings=optiontohead,  %uses the short statement in the chapter/section command for the running head. \chapter[short stement]{heading title} => work on the ones already created.
headinclude=false,
footinclude=false,
headsepline=true,
footnotes=multiple
]{scrbook}                  % KOMA -script class : scrbook


\usepackage{xcolor}                             % color

\definecolor{fh_blue}{cmyk}{0.62, 0.15, 0, 0.08}            
\definecolor{fh_blue2}{cmyk}{0.82, 0.23, 0, 0}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}                        % to import pdfs

\usepackage[german,english]{babel}              % language packages included, English set as main language

% ====== Glossaries and indexes ======
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

% ====== Hyperref package !LAST TO BE LOADED! ======
\usepackage[draft=false,bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
%   hyperindex=true,                % Makes the page numbers of index entries into hyperlinks, not needed due to the linktocpage
    linktoc=all,                    % Makes the page numbers and text to be link in the Table of content.
    linktocpage=true,               % Makes the page numbers only to be link in the Table of content etc.
    breaklinks=true,                % Allows links to be broken into multiple lines. 
    colorlinks=true,                % Colours the text for links and anchors, these colors will appear in the printed version   
    linkcolor=fh_blue,              % Colour for normal internal links
    citecolor=fh_blue2,             % color for citations 
    urlcolor=black,             % Colour for linked URLs 
    anchorcolor=black,              % Colour for anchor (target) text 
    frenchlinks=false,              % Use small caps instead of colors for links 
% ====== pdf specific hyperref options ======
    pdftitle={title},               % Sets the .pdf Title
    pdfauthor={who knowsi},         % Sets the document Author. 
    bookmarksopen=true,         % Bookmarks are shown with all sub-trees expanded. 
    pdfhighlight=/N,                % no change when selecting pdf links
    pdfpagemode=UseOutlines,        % open with open bookmarks
    pdfstartpage=1,             % Determines on which page the PDF file is opened. 
    pdfkeywords={x},
    pdfdisplaydoctitle=true,            % display document title instead of file name in title bar
    pdftoolbar=false,               % hides the pdf toolbar
    pdfpagelayout=OneColumn     % Displays the document in one column; continuous scrolling.s
}

\usepackage[all]{hypcap}                % to make pdf jumps to the top of the element, not the caption (e.g. directly figure)   


\begin{document}

\frontmatter                            % does roman numbering for starting pages
\setcounter{page}{1}

\tableofcontents                        % generates table of contents


\mainmatter                         % does arabic numbering for main part

\chapter{Results}
\includepdf[trim=25mm 25mm 25mm 30mm, clip, pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}, offset=6mm 20mm, pages={1-}, scale=0.7,
    addtotoc={
    1, section, 1, {somuchtext}, {results:ijms},
    1, subsection, 2, {Introduction}, ijmsIntro,
    3, subsection, 2, {Results}, ijmsRes,     
    10, subsection, 2, {Discussion}, ijmsDis,
    11, subsection, 2, {Material and Methods}, ijmsMnM
    },  
    addtolist={
    3, figure, {fig1}, ijmsFig1,
    5, figure, {fig2}, ijmsFig2
}   
]{publications/ijms.pdf}

\listoffigures

\end{document}


% ===== end of it =====
```

the entries in the .toc look like:

```
\babel@toc {english}{}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}Results}{1}{chapter.1}%
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.1}}{2}{section.1.1}%
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.1.1}}{2}{subsection.1.1.1}%
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.1.2}}{4}{subsection.1.1.2}%
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.1.3}}{11}{subsection.1.1.3}%
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.1.4}}{12}{subsection.1.1.4}%
\contentsline {chapter}{\nonumberline List of Figures}{17}{chapter*.2}%
```

When I manually modify the toc and re-compile I get them to work in the toc, but not in the pdf bookmarks.

```
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.1}somuchtext}{2}{section.1.1}%
```

[image]

And yes, I am aware that this function is still termed "Experimental", however any hint is highly appreciated! :)

Best, Chris

Answer (score 1):

pdfpages gets confused by the `heading=optiontohead`. Change it locally to the standard  `optiontoheadandtoc`:

```
\documentclass[
headings=optiontohead,
]{scrbook}                  % KOMA -script class : scrbook

\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}          
\usepackage[german,english]{babel}    

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter                          
\tableofcontents                      

\mainmatter                         
\chapter{Results}

\KOMAoptions{headings=optiontoheadandtoc}
\includepdf[pages={1}, 
    addtotoc={
    1, section, 1, {somuchtext}, {results:ijms}
}
]{example-image-duck}

\listoffigures
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a thousand times!!!!!!!! Finally it works :-)